# how to bind a POJO bean to common header page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring tiles framework to map the view and each page contains header (a common JSP header page) + body (the real view).

The `tiles-definition.xml` looks like as follows:

```
 <definition extends="defaultTemplate" name="dashboard">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home/mainPageHeader.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home/dashboard.jsp" />
 </definition>
```

Till now, `mainPageHeader.jsp` was static page but now I want to bind some bean to this header page as well. But its not working, I tried as follows in my `dashboard` controller:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
model.addObject("dashboardBean", dashboardObj); // bean related to dashboard page 
model.addObject("headerBean", headerObject); // new bean sending for header page.
return model;
```

But when the dashboard page loads, I can see exception as:

```
Error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target
object for bean name 'headerBean' available as request attribute.
```

I can understand the issue, that headerBean which I am passing with the model is not getting associated with view. But haven't got any clue for how to bind the bean with this common header page.

Comment: Could you also show mainPageHeader.jsp? Is this header page used on other pages as well? Maybe you are experiencing a side-effect that a headerBean now needs to be present in every view that uses the mainPageHeader.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Try using *addAttribute* rather than addObject

i.e

`ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
model.addAttribute("dashboardBean", dashboardObj); // bean related to dashboard page 
model.addAttribute("headerBean", headerObject); // new bean sending for header page.
return model;`